# How to use "Pull to refresh" in top and (at the same time) in bottom in a FlatList in React Native?

Tags: javascript, react-native, jsx

I need in my React-Native app to have a Pull to refresh on the top of my FlatList and at the same time a Pull to refresh in the bottom of that FlatList. I can use refreshControl to use it at the top but I don't know what to do to put it in both top and bottom.

Answer (score 0):

The FlatList component has predefined functions for that. As i understand you want to be able to refresh via pull to refresh and when you are reaching the end of the list? If so, you can do the following:

```
handleRefresh = () => {
//make api calls 
};
```

```
<FlatList
   data={yourData}
   onRefresh{this.handleRefresh} // handle pull to refresh 
   onEndReached={this.handleRefresh} // handle refresh 
   onEndReachedThreshold={1} // refresh as soon as the end of the list is reached. Probably you have to play around with this value 
   ListFooterComponent={this.renderFooter(this.props.loading)} // show activity indicator 
/>
```

Comment: No, I need to show the pull refresh animation when I reach the end of the list and the start of the list. (Understanding "to reach" as to make "Pull to refresh"'s gesture)

Comment: i edited my post. I think it's impossible to add a pull to refresh gesture. Instead you could render an activity indicator, when your are reaching the end. So it's an automatically pull without gesture.

Comment: The onEndReached .

Comment: Yes, I'm trying now to put my flat list inside a ScrollView and put refreshControl to it, I can use Refreshcontrol in 1 of them separateds, but id I put it to both it only work to Scroll View(I want this because my FlatList is inverted so, I have the refresh in the bottom and I want to use refresh of the Scroll view in the top)  (Sorry my english T_T)